Computing a Gaussian expectation
I am curious what the Bernstein-Orlicz norm of a (centered) Gaussian is. My Gaussians have pdf proportional to $\exp(-x^2/(2\sigma^2))$.
I thus need to compute
$$\tag{1}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp(-x^2/(2\sigma^2)) \exp(\Psi_L(|x|/c)
)\mathrm{d}x,$$
where $c, L>0$ are constants, and
$$\Psi_L(x) = \exp\left[\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+2Lx}-1}{L}\right)^2\right]-1.$$
I believe there should be another way to (indirectly) compute the quantity I'm interested in (combine Lemma 2 of the quoted paper with standard tail bounds). I'm interested if the integral of Eq. (1) may be given a closed-form (or at least tightly upper-bounded) though.
